# Expose port other than 80/443 in GKE ingress loadbalancer?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

We are using GKE with their own ingress loadbalancer, we need to be able to connect to ports other than 80/443 e.g `https://www.example.com:5000/hello`for legacy reasons. Any solutions ?

Comment: Are you using  [GKE Ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce) or [NGINX Ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/) ?

Comment: GKE ingress controller

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only ports supported by Ingress are 80 and 443, for now.